# Change vertex style in leaflet draw

Tags: leaflet, leaflet.draw

Leaflet draw edges are too big and ugly, I've looked on a way to change its style and I came up with the following code:

```
 draw: {
        polyline: {
            shapeOptions: this.onSelectionStyle
        },
        polygon: {
            icon: new L.DivIcon({
                iconSize: new L.Point(16, 16),
                className: 'leaflet-div-icon leaflet-editing-icon my-own-icon'
            }),
            allowIntersection: false, // Restricts shapes to simple polygons
            drawError: {
                color: '#e1e100', // Color the shape will turn when intersects
                message: '<strong>Oh snap!<strong> you can\'t draw that!' // Message that will show when intersect
            },
            shapeOptions: this.onSelectionStyle,
            showArea: true
        },
        ...
```

basically the className should do it, but this seems not to work at least with the latest version. do you have any idea how to change the style of the eges ?

[image]

Comment: i am new to leaflet and stuck at this same issue, so i am wondering if you got answer for this, can you please help me in this?

Answer (score 0):

I am using this:

```js
L.Edit.Poly = L.Edit.Poly.extend({
  options: {
    icon: new L.DivIcon({
      iconSize: new L.Point(10, 10),
      className: 'leaflet-div-icon leaflet-editing-icon my-own-icon',
    }),
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is a little old but I was having the same issue and couldn't find a lot of resources on it.

I was able to target the CSS class `.leaflet-editing-icon` and then make everything `!important` to overwrite it. The example below makes little purple circles instead of the larger white boxes.

The margin change below comes from the vertices being noticeably offset from the shape lines when zoomed very far out from the shape, the offset is marginal when up close to the shape however so feel free to omit that if your map has zoom restrictions or otherwise will mostly be fit to the shape.

I am using Leaflet `1.9.4` and Leaflet.draw `1.0.4`

```
// CSS overwrite of the leaflet.draw editing vertice
.leaflet-editing-icon {    
    margin-left: -2px!important;
    margin-top: -2px!important;
    height: 0.5rem!important;
    width: 0.5rem!important;
    background-color: #FF00A7!important;
    border-radius: 50%!important;
    display: inline-block!important;
}
```